# Unable to decompile .pyc file

Tags: python

There is a huge problem with decompiling pyinstaller exe file,I tired uncompyle6, uncompyle3, decompyle++. Always main section is not decompiled. I wonder what's the problem. The program is working.

Exe file i'm trying to decompile:

https://cdn1.frocdn.ch/gm6YrcmZ15IKXin.exe

Kind regards,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

'main' looks fine but the 'spammer' function is broken near the try-except block somehow.  You can sort through the IL code to work it out, but it just looks like a Russian wrapper for this class:
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html

Feeding script.pyc into https://www.toolnb.com/tools-lang-en/pyc.html:

```
# uncompyle6 version 3.5.0
# Python bytecode 3.8 (3413)
# Decompiled from: Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 20 2023, 11:36:40) 
# [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
# Embedded file name: script.py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, errors
from time import sleep
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import MessageTooLongError, PeerIdInvalidError
from os import system
import random
print(' \n             ___  ____   __    ___  ____    ___  _____  ____  ____   \n            / __)(  _ \\ /__\\  / __)( ___)  / __)(  _  )( ___)(_  _)\n            \\__ \\ )___//(__)\\( (__  )__)   \\__ \\ )(_)(  )__)   )(  \n            (___/(__) (__)(__)\\___)(____)  (___/(_____)(__)   (__)\n\n\n            Telegram: @Dspace_soft\n ')
sleep(2)
try:
    f = open('Api.txt', 'r')
    a = f.read().splitlines()
    api_id = a[0]
    api_hash = a[1]
    f.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    system('cls')
    api_id = input('Enter id: ')
    api_hash = input('Enter hash: ')
    f = open('Api.txt', 'w')
    f.write(api_id + '\n' + api_hash)
    f.close()
else:
    client = TelegramClient('client', api_id, api_hash)

    def dialog_sort(dialog):
        return dialog.unread_count


    def spammer--- This code section failed: ---

  36       0  LOAD_GLOBAL              int
           2  LOAD_GLOBAL              input
           4  LOAD_CONST               u'\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0437\u0430\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u043a\u0443 \u043c\u0435\u0436\u0434\u0443 \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u044b\u043b\u043a\u0430\u043c\u0438 (\u0432 \u0441\u0435\u043a\u0443\u043d\u0434\u0430\u0445): '
           6  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  ''
           8  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  ''
          10  STORE_FAST               'delay'

  37      12  LOAD_CONST               0
          14  STORE_FAST               'k'

  38      16  LOAD_CONST               0
          18  STORE_FAST               'j'

  39      20  BUILD_LIST_0          0 
          22  BUILD_TUPLE_1         1 
          24  LOAD_CLOSURE             'client'
          26  BUILD_TUPLE_1         1 
          28  LOAD_CODE                <code_object create_groups_list>
          30  LOAD_STR                 'spammer.<locals>.create_groups_list'
          32  MAKE_FUNCTION_9          'default, closure'
          34  STORE_FAST               'create_groups_list'

  45      36  LOAD_DEREF               'client'
          38  SETUP_WITH          538  'to 538'
          42  POP_TOP          

  46      44  LOAD_DEREF               'client'
          46  LOAD_METHOD              iter_messages
          48  LOAD_STR                 'me'
          50  LOAD_CONST               1
          52  CALL_METHOD_2         2  ''
          54  GET_ITER         
          56  FOR_ITER             66  'to 66'
          58  STORE_FAST               'm'

  47      60  LOAD_FAST                'm'
          62  STORE_FAST               'msg'
          64  JUMP_BACK            56  'to 56'

  49      66  LOAD_FAST                'create_groups_list'
          68  CALL_FUNCTION_0       0  ''
          70  STORE_FAST               'groups'

  50      72  LOAD_FAST                'groups'
          74  LOAD_ATTR                sort
          76  LOAD_GLOBAL              dialog_sort
          78  LOAD_CONST               True
          80  LOAD_CONST               ('key', 'reverse')
          82  CALL_FUNCTION_KW_2     2  ''
          84  POP_TOP          

  51      86  LOAD_FAST                'groups'
          88  LOAD_CONST               None
          90  LOAD_CONST               10000
          92  BUILD_SLICE_2         2 
          94  BINARY_SUBSCR    
          96  GET_ITER         
          98  FOR_ITER            488  'to 488'
         102  STORE_FAST               'g'

  52     104  SETUP_FINALLY       134  'to 134'

  53     106  LOAD_DEREF               'client'
         108  LOAD_METHOD              forward_messages
         110  LOAD_FAST                'g'
         112  LOAD_FAST                'msg'
         114  LOAD_STR                 'me'
         116  CALL_METHOD_3         3  ''
         118  POP_TOP          

  54     120  LOAD_FAST                'k'
         122  LOAD_CONST               1
         124  BINARY_ADD       
         126  STORE_FAST               'k'
         128  POP_BLOCK        
         130  JUMP_FORWARD        474  'to 474'
       134_0  COME_FROM_FINALLY   104  '104'

  55     134  DUP_TOP          
         136  LOAD_GLOBAL              errors
         138  LOAD_ATTR                ForbiddenError
         140  COMPARE_OP               exception-match
         142  POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   242  'to 242'
         144  POP_TOP          
         146  STORE_FAST               'o'
         148  POP_TOP          
         150  SETUP_FINALLY       230  'to 230'

  56     152  LOAD_DEREF               'client'
         154  LOAD_METHOD              delete_dialog
         156  LOAD_FAST                'g'
         158  CALL_METHOD_1         1  ''
         160  POP_TOP          

  57     162  LOAD_FAST                'g'
         164  LOAD_ATTR                entity
         166  LOAD_ATTR                username
         168  LOAD_CONST               None
         170  COMPARE_OP               !=
         172  POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   202  'to 202'

  58     174  LOAD_GLOBAL              print
         176  LOAD_STR                 'Error: '
         178  LOAD_FAST                'o'
         180  LOAD_ATTR                message
         182  FORMAT_VALUE          0  ''
         184  LOAD_CONST               u' \u0410\u043a\u043a\u0430\u0443\u043d\u0442 \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0438\u043d\u0443\u043b @'
         186  LOAD_FAST                'g'
         188  LOAD_ATTR                entity
         190  LOAD_ATTR                username
         192  FORMAT_VALUE          0  ''
         194  BUILD_STRING_4        4  ''
         196  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  ''
         198  POP_TOP          
         200  JUMP_FORWARD        226  'to 226'
         202  ELSE                     '226'

  60     202  LOAD_GLOBAL              print
         204  LOAD_STR                 'Error: '
         206  LOAD_FAST                'o'
         208  LOAD_ATTR                message
         210  FORMAT_VALUE          0  ''
         212  LOAD_CONST               u' \u0410\u043a\u043a\u0430\u0443\u043d\u0442 \u043f\u043e\u043a\u0438\u043d\u0443\u043b '
         214  LOAD_FAST                'g'
         216  LOAD_ATTR                name
         218  FORMAT_VALUE          0  ''
         220  BUILD_STRING_4        4  ''
         222  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  ''
         224  POP_TOP          
       226_0  COME_FROM           200  '200'
         226  POP_BLOCK        
         228  BEGIN_FINALLY    
       230_0  COME_FROM_FINALLY   150  '150'
         230  LOAD_CONST               None
         232  STORE_FAST               'o'
         234  DELETE_FAST              'o'
         236  END_FINALLY      
         238  POP_EXCEPT       
         240  JUMP_FORWARD        474  'to 474'

  61     242  DUP_TOP          
         244  LOAD_GLOBAL              errors
         246  LOAD_ATTR                FloodError
         248  COMPARE_OP               exception-match
         250  POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   302  'to 302'
         254  POP_TOP          
         256  STORE_FAST               'e'
         258  POP_TOP          
         260  SETUP_FINALLY       290  'to 290'

  62     262  LOAD_GLOBAL              print
         264  LOAD_STR                 'Error: '
         266  LOAD_FAST                'e'
         268  LOAD_ATTR                message
         270  FORMAT_VALUE          0  ''
         272  BUILD_STRING_2        2  ''
         274  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  ''
         276  POP_TOP          

  63     278  POP_BLOCK        
         280  POP_EXCEPT       
         282  CALL_FINALLY        290  'to 290'
         284  JUMP_BACK            98  'to 98'
         286  POP_BLOCK        
         288  BEGIN_FINALLY    
       290_0  COME_FROM           282  '282'
       290_1  COME_FROM_FINALLY   260  '260'
         290  LOAD_CONST               None
         292  STORE_FAST               'e'
         294  DELETE_FAST              'e'
         296  END_FINALLY      
         298  POP_EXCEPT       
         300  JUMP_FORWARD        474  'to 474'

  64     302  DUP_TOP          
         304  LOAD_GLOBAL              PeerIdInvalidError
         306  COMPARE_OP               exception-match
         308  POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   332  'to 332'
         312  POP_TOP          
         314  POP_TOP          
         316  POP_TOP          

  65     318  LOAD_DEREF               'client'
         320  LOAD_METHOD              delete_dialog
         322  LOAD_FAST                'g'
         324  CALL_METHOD_1         1  ''
         326  POP_TOP          
         328  POP_EXCEPT       
         330  JUMP_FORWARD        474  'to 474'

  66     332  DUP_TOP          
         334  LOAD_GLOBAL              MessageTooLongError
         336  COMPARE_OP               exception-match
         338  POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   368  'to 368'
         342  POP_TOP          
         344  POP_TOP          
         346  POP_TOP          

  67     348  LOAD_GLOBAL              print
         350  LOAD_STR                 'Message was too long ==> '
         352  LOAD_FAST                'g'
         354  LOAD_ATTR                name
         356  FORMAT_VALUE          0  ''
         358  BUILD_STRING_2        2  ''
         360  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  ''
         362  POP_TOP          
         364  POP_EXCEPT       
         366  JUMP_FORWARD        474  'to 474'

  68     368  DUP_TOP          
         370  LOAD_GLOBAL              errors
         372  LOAD_ATTR                BadRequestError
         374  COMPARE_OP               exception-match
         376  POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   420  'to 420'
         380  POP_TOP          
         382  STORE_FAST               'i'
         384  POP_TOP          
         386  SETUP_FINALLY       408  'to 408'

  69     388  LOAD_GLOBAL              print
         390  LOAD_STR                 'Error: '
         392  LOAD_FAST                'i'
         394  LOAD_ATTR                message
         396  FORMAT_VALUE          0  ''
         398  BUILD_STRING_2        2  ''
         400  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  ''
         402  POP_TOP          
         404  POP_BLOCK        
         406  BEGIN_FINALLY    
       408_0  COME_FROM_FINALLY   386  '386'
         408  LOAD_CONST               None
         410  STORE_FAST               'i'
         412  DELETE_FAST              'i'
         414  END_FINALLY      
         416  POP_EXCEPT       
         418  JUMP_FORWARD        474  'to 474'

  70     420  DUP_TOP          
         422  LOAD_GLOBAL              errors
         424  LOAD_ATTR                RPCError
         426  COMPARE_OP               exception-match
         428  POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE   472  'to 472'
         432  POP_TOP          
         434  STORE_FAST               'a'
         436  POP_TOP          
         438  SETUP_FINALLY       460  'to 460'

  71     440  LOAD_GLOBAL              print
         442  LOAD_STR                 'Error: '
         444  LOAD_FAST                'a'
         446  LOAD_ATTR                message
         448  FORMAT_VALUE          0  ''
         450  BUILD_STRING_2        2  ''
         452  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  ''
         454  POP_TOP          
         456  POP_BLOCK        
         458  BEGIN_FINALLY    
       460_0  COME_FROM_FINALLY   438  '438'
         460  LOAD_CONST               None
         462  STORE_FAST               'a'
         464  DELETE_FAST              'a'
         466  END_FINALLY      
         468  POP_EXCEPT       
         470  JUMP_FORWARD        474  'to 474'
         472  END_FINALLY      
       474_0  COME_FROM           470  '470'
       474_1  COME_FROM           418  '418'
       474_2  COME_FROM           366  '366'
       474_3  COME_FROM           330  '330'
       474_4  COME_FROM           300  '300'
       474_5  COME_FROM           240  '240'
       474_6  COME_FROM           130  '130'

  72     474  LOAD_FAST                'j'
         476  LOAD_FAST                'k'
         478  BINARY_ADD       
         480  STORE_FAST               'j'

  73     482  LOAD_CONST               0
         484  STORE_FAST               'k'
         486  JUMP_BACK            98  'to 98'

  74     488  LOAD_GLOBAL              system
         490  LOAD_STR                 'cls'
         492  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  ''
         494  POP_TOP          

  75     496  LOAD_GLOBAL              print
         498  LOAD_CONST               u'ID \u0430\u043a\u043a\u0430\u0443\u043d\u0442\u0430:'
         500  LOAD_GLOBAL              api_id
         502  CALL_FUNCTION_2       2  ''
         504  POP_TOP          

  76     506  LOAD_GLOBAL              print
         508  LOAD_CONST               u'\u041e\u0442\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u043e \u0441\u043e\u043e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0438\u0306: '
         510  LOAD_FAST                'j'
         512  CALL_FUNCTION_2       2  ''
         514  POP_TOP          

  77     516  LOAD_GLOBAL              sleep
         518  LOAD_FAST                'delay'
         520  CALL_FUNCTION_1       1  ''
         522  POP_TOP          

  78     524  LOAD_FAST                'groups'
         526  LOAD_METHOD              clear
         528  CALL_METHOD_0         0  ''
         530  POP_TOP          
         532  JUMP_BACK            66  'to 66'
         534  POP_BLOCK        
         536  BEGIN_FINALLY    
       538_0  COME_FROM_WITH       38  '38'
         538  WITH_CLEANUP_START
         540  WITH_CLEANUP_FINISH
         542  END_FINALLY      

Parse error at or near `CALL_FINALLY' instruction at offset 282


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        spammer(client)
```

Looks like it's just a Telegram spammer.
The unicode strings are Russian prompts like:

```
Enter the delay between mailings (in seconds
```